# Python inserting additional \'s?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, special-characters

Background: I'm working with python 3.2 in Eclipse SDK 4.2.1 (Juno), and I noticed something strange - while my programs run perfectly in Eclipse, they always close with an error if I open them from the file manager. I managed to get a screenshot before the cmd closed: [image]

It seems that the program is inserting an additional "\" between "images" and "Cy.png".  However, I can't just remove a slash from my program - in it, I used two slashes because you need to to include a slash in a string.
My program is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image

def pathConstruction(count, imageName):
    l = []
    l.append('images\\')
    if count == 1:
        l.append('Sepia')
    l.append(imageName)
    imagePath = ''.join(l)
    return imagePath

def grayscale(pix, width, height):
    for col in range(width):
        for row in range(height):
            r,g,b = pix[col, row]
            avg = ((r + g + b) / 3)
            r = int(avg)
            g = int(avg)
            b = int(avg)
            pix[col, row] = r,g,b

def sepia(pix, width, height):
    for col in range(width):
        for row in range(height):
            r,g,b = pix[col, row]
            newR = (r * 0.393 + g * 0.769 + b * 0.189)
            newG = (r * 0.349 + g * 0.686 + b * 0.168)
            newB = (r * 0.272 + g * 0.534 + b * 0.131)
            pix[col, row] = int(newR),int(newG),int(newB)

imageName = input("Please input the full name of your image, including extension: ")
count = 0
imagePath= pathConstruction(count, imageName)
count = count + 1

img = Image.open(imagePath)
pix = img.load()
width, height = img.size

grayscale(pix, width, height)
sepia(pix, width, height)

imagePath = pathConstruction(count, imageName)
img.save(imagePath)
img.show()
```

Question: What can I do to run this program outside of Eclipse?

Comment: you could set `sys.excepthook` to a function that logs uncaught exceptions to a file. You can log to a file without waiting for the program to exit, setup: `logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)`, log: `logging.info('message')`.

Comment: I determined the actual issue - question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Configure logging and add `logging.debug(repr(imageName))` after `input()`. Do you see `\r` at the of image name in example.log?

Comment: Yeah, there was a `\r` after the image name, like in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not the extra backslash you're seeing between the directory and the file name (which I think it just from the `repr` of the string), but instead the `\r` that's added at the end. I'm not sure why you'd get that included in the value from `input`, but you can remove it by calling `strip` on the string.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by calling `strip` on the string?

Comment: The `imageName` string is getting a carriage return on the end. Call `strip` on it after you get it back from `input` (e.g. `imageName = input("whatever").strip()`, or something similar. If the filename had simply had an extra `\` it would have still worked (on Windows, at least). The base `IOError` is also not what you'd get if the filename simply didn't refer to the right thing (you'd get a `FileNotFoundError` if there was nothing under the name you gave).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the built-in os.path module.  It will be simpler and more reliable.

```
def pathConstruction(count, imageName):
    import os
    dir = "images"
    if count == 1:
        imageName = "Sepia" + imageName
    return os.path.join(dir, imageName)
```

Comment: That still got the same traceback/IOError as before, with it inserting the second `\\`.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you get the same results if you replace "images\\" with r"images\" in the original code?

Comment: If you mean using `l.append(r'images\\')`, then I got an error: `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'images\\\\Cy.png\r'`

Comment: No, with a raw string (which is indicated by the `r` prefix), you'd only need one backslash.  Though the results of what you did suggest it's not going to work either.

Comment: Last question: what happens if you use a forward slash instead of backslashes?

Comment: Yeah, using `'images/'` worked as well! Thanks for the input! Do you know how this works? I thought Windows used `\\` for its filesystem.

Comment: Also, I probably going to use your pathConstruction function instead of mine, since yours is much simpler looking.

Comment: It's just some convenient magic you get by using the os library.  The whole point is to abstract away os details like path separators.  Have fun.